# How to make svg text editable when an svg node?

Tags: svg, d3.js, contenteditable

The following code gives a nice editable svg text box (in Chrome at least):

```
d3.select("body").append("text").text("Test").attr("contentEditable","true");
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
d3.select("svg").append("text").text("Test").attr("contentEditable","true");
```

Is there any way to make svg text editable along the lines of the second snippet above? I'm really hoping to avoid foreignObject if possible.

Comment: The first is not an SVG text box. SVG doesn't provide interactive elements in the same way as HTML does. You'll have to use `foreignObject` for that.