# How can I edit a svg.js text node at any time?

Tags: svg, textnode, svg.js

I find I can't edit a svg text node at any time like HTML node by using "contenteditable" attribute. How mightI solve it? I have referred to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063221/how-to-make-svg-text-editable-when-an-svg-node?answertab=oldest#tab-top). But it doesn't work.

How can I get the result that when I double-click a svg text node to edit it?

Please provide an example if you can explain it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Old Questions desereve an answer, too. So here it is:

`contenteditable` is not in the SVG1.1 Specs which means it does not work.
However you can make the sorrounnding html editable which causes the whole svg to be editable.
I anyway suggest NOT to do that because it most likely will destroy the whole svg when you try to edit it.

In the SVG2 specs the `contenteditable` attribute will be present!